# Undefined reference to `(anonymous namespace)::

Tags: c++, compilation, namespaces

I have a namespace that I am currently using in two classes. When I try to compile my project, I get that error but my namespace is not anonymous!

One of my classes looks like this:

```
//margin.cpp
#include <math.h>
#include "margin.h"
#include "anotherClass.h"
#include "specificMath.nsp.h" //My namespace

double margin::doSomeMath(double a, double b){
    return specificMath::math_function1(0, 1, 0);
    // Just a simpler, random example
}
```

My namespace looks like this:

```
//specificMath.nsp.h
#ifndef specificMath
#define specificMath
namespace specificMath {
     double math_function1(double, double, double);
     double math_function1(double);
     //more functions
}
```

---

```
 //specificMath.nsp.cpp
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include "constants.h"
 #include "specificMath.nsp.h"

 namespace specificMath{
     double math_function1(double a, double b, double c){
          //some code
     }
     ... more functions
 }
```

When I try to compile, it seems to compile fine, but when linking (and I've been doing "make clean" to make sure it's using the new files) I get an error saying:

```
margin.o: In function `margin::doSomeMath(double, double)':
margin.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `(anonymous namespace)::math_function1(double, double, double)'
```

Why does it think it's an anonymous namespace? How can I fix this?

I compile doing this:

```
g++ -I. -c -w *.h *.cpp
```

And then...

```
g++ -o myProgram *.o
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You `#define`d the namespace name away. After the preprocessor sees `#define specificMath`, then it finds all instances of `specificMath` after that and replaces them with what you `#define`d it to, which in this case, is nothing. So it simply eliminates it.

```
#ifndef specificMath
#define specificMath
namespace specificMath {
```

After the preprocessor runs

```
namespace {
```

Always use all capitals for macros, and never prepend underscores to them.

```
#ifndef SPECIFIC_MATH_FUNCTIONS
```

for example.

Answer (score 4):

It think it is an anonymous namespace because you made it anonymous with

```
#define specificMath
```

so "specificMath" will expand to nothing.

You could give the definition an identifier, e.g.

```
#define specificMath specificMath
```

or just don't use the same identifier for both the include guard and namespace.

```
#ifndef SPECIFIC_MATH_H
#define SPECIFIC_MATH_H
namespace specificMath { ... }
#endif
```

Comment: Don't think the preprocessor can cope with that?

Comment: @DeadMG: Cope with what? `#define specificMath specificMath` is fine because expansion is not recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Your ifdef macros are interfering with your mamespace names.